# Cakephp testing login

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp-1.3, simpletest

I want to test login function if it works propperly and only lets valid and active users in.

My user fixture contains:

```
array(
        'password' => '*emptyPasswordHash*', // empty password
        'username' => 'Lorem',
        'balance' => 0,
        'currency' => 'USD',
        'id' => 1,
        'user_group_id' => 3, //Customer
        'active' => 1,
        'hash' => 'LoremHash'
    ),
```

My test function looks like this:

```
function testLogin() {
            //test valid login
            $result = $this->testAction('/users/login', array(
                'data' => array(
                    'User' => array(
                        'username' => 'Lorem',
                        'pass' => '',
                        'remember' => true
                )),
                'method' => 'post',
                'return' => 'view'
            ));

            debug($result);
```

}

The login form has 3 inputs: `username`, `password` and `remember`

I have set `$this->Auth->autoRedirect = false;` in the `UsersController::beforeFilter` and I am doing some cookie setting stuff

when I `debug($this->data);` in `UsersController::login()` it shows the exact same data when testing and when logging normaly. But while testing the login fails and I get `$this->Auth->loginError` message instead of a login.

How do I test login action propperly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use cakes Auth component and dont hack it up you dont need to...

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/cake/tests/cases/libs/controller/components/auth.test.php#L545

and if you really want to, look at how the pro's do it :)

Comment: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/26d526f6240239094aa714b86093cd36fbb9a1f3/cake/tests/cases/libs/controller/components/auth.test.php#L561

Answer (score 0):

Did you also set your custom function, like described in The [CakePHP manual](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1265/AuthComponent-Variables#authorize-1275):

> Normally, the AuthComponent will
>   attempt to verify that the login
>   credentials you've entered are
>   accurate by comparing them to what's
>   been stored in your user model.
>   However, there are times where you
>   might want to do some additional work
>   in determining proper credentials. By
>   setting this variable to one of
>   several different values, you can do
>   different things.